# Salesforce: Enabling OAuth for app

Tags: oauth, salesforce

I'm toying around with a sandbox dev account on salesforce. I'm trying to create an app with OAuth settings similar to [these](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm) instructions, but I can't find any option to enable OAuth settings.

Here's a walkthrough of what I see:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Where was "Enable OAuth Settings"?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add the new app under "connected apps" instead of "apps"

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati, is this better?